# How to tell when an exe gets fired on Windows?

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a way to tell if an executable gets fired in Windows. I can't watch the Task Manager because the exe sometimes gets fired for just a split second.

Is there any way to get some visual clue the exe is getting fired?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from the Microsoft Sysinternals Suite is an alternative to the Task Manager and has a useful feature in that it colour codes created and deleted tasks for you.

A task that dies will linger for a few seconds in the list but be coloured red to show that it has gone, a newly created task will be green I believe.

Comment: The highlight duration and colors are configurable, too.

Comment: To make Mokubai's answer complete, on Process Explorer's menu: "View -> Update Speed" you can change the refresh rate so that newly-launched processes linger on the list (even if they were immediately closed) for 5, 10, on unlimited (paused) time.  (For paused you have to refresh to see changes (new processes, ended processes)).

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there's some highly technical way.  As a Windows non-expert I would rename the executable and replace it with a script (batch file) that writes the time and date to some text file, then starts the real program.

Answer (score 3):

**SysInternals [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)**, with "Thread activity" enabled.

Comment: How is Thread Activity enabled?  I'm unable to find that option on the menus, toolbars, or help file.  v2.93  Ah found it, the 4th button on the last set of toolbar buttons, "Show Process and Thread Activity".  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Robert: It's the second-to-last button on the toolbar. You can also do it by removing "`Event Class` is `Process`" from the filter.

Answer (score 2):

**Each executable has [Image File Execution options](http://blogs.mcafee.com/mcafee-labs/image-file-execution-options) in the registry**. Their purpose is to allow a debugger to intercept the starting of certain applications (otherwise it is very difficult to debug the startup code of the application), but any executable may be used. Note this executable is responsible for starting the application; the full commandline is passed to the executable.

[MSDN step-by-step instructions for using Image File Execution options.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=VS.100).aspx)